# Change hard code parameter to dynamic parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

In our current example, in order to make the expand function work, we need to hard code the id #expand_product_images_xxxx in javascript so that it can trigger the function. Remark: I am using jquerymobile 1.3.2 in my programme.

e.g. click Test

```
    <a href="" id="expand_product_images_2978">Test</a>
```

trigger to show the tab "selection_product_estate_image_2978"

```
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="selection_product_estate_images_2978>
```

As our id is dynamic for different product, what is the way to change the following hard code product id to dynamic product id?

```
$("#expand_product_images_2978") .on("click", function() {$("#selection_product_images_2978").trigger("expand");})
$("#expand_product_estate_structure_2978") .on("click", function() {$("#selection_product_estate_structure_2978").trigger("expand");})
$("#expand_product_estate_images_2978") .on("click", function() {$("#selection_product_estate_images_2978").trigger("expand");})    

$("#expand_product_images_6938") .on("click", function() {$("#selection_product_images_6938").trigger("expand");})
$("#expand_product_estate_structure_6938") .on("click", function() {$("#selection_product_estate_structure_6938").trigger("expand");})
$("#expand_product_estate_images_6938") .on("click", function() {$("#selection_product_estate_images_6938").trigger("expand");})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a selector of your desire (class, id, nesting) to the elements that you wish to expand and then use jQuery to process them. The code below can explain this better.

I would do something like this, considering that you have the following html:

### HTML

```
 <div>
    <a href="" id="expand_product_images_2978">Test 1</a>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="selection_product_estate_images_2978"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <a href="" id="expand_product_images_2979">Test 2</a>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="selection_product_estate_images_2979"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <a href="" id="expand_product_images_2980">Test 3</a>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="selection_product_estate_images_2980"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <a href="" id="expand_product_images_2981">Test 4</a>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="selection_product_estate_images_2981"></div>
  </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var expand = function(event){
  // the link element
  var $a = $(this);
  // link id
  var id = $a.attr('id'); 
  // get the uid form link id
  var uid = id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
  // get the colapsable element
  var $colapsable = $('#selection_product_estate_images_'+uid); 
  $colapsable.trigger('expand');                                                  
  // stop event propagation
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
};

// Attach on click events on links 
$('a[id*="expand_product_images_"]').on('click', expand);
```

Demo available here: http://jsbin.com/wugey/2/edit

Comment: Btw, if I have several tabs like this, say selection_product_estate_images_, selection_product_estate_info_, selection_product_estate_details_, etc. What is the simplest way to refine the above code?

Comment: btw, if i use my original code, the tab is highlighted when I click on it. However, when I use the code as suggested, it's not highlighted. You may see the difference from http://jsbin.com/jopax/5/edit?html,js,output and http://jsbin.com/jopax/4/edit?html,js,output Thanks so much again for your kind help!

Comment: So for each tab you have an expandable, right ? than you need  a mapping between tabs and expandables or a pattern between the tabs and the exapandables.

Here you have an example with the mapping :
http://jsbin.com/fapop/1/edit
Here you have an example with a pattern in the naming - drawback: you need to strictly follow a naming convention: 
http://jsbin.com/xoxug/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

you could add a function and send the object's id that is clicked like this in html:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="expand_product_images_2978" onclick="expandFunc(this.id)">Test</a>
<div data-role="collapsible" id="selection_product_estate_images_2978">
```

and in js you capture the id of the object and split it to get dynamic id into a variable, then use it to trigger expand on the other object:

```
function expandFunc(id)
{
    var idArr = id.split("_");
    var realId = idArr[idArr.length-1];
    $("#selection_product_estate_images_" + realId ).trigger("expand");
}
```

Comment: As I am using jquerymobile, instead of using onclick=, can it align the jquerymobile format which uses id="expand_product_image_xxxx"?

Comment: you can use onclick with jquery mobile. just make sure to add `rel="external"` to your object.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function with parameter like this:

```
function expand(id) {
   $("#selection_product_images_"+id).trigger("expand");
}
```

And call this function in your link's onclick event, e.g. supposing you are using php (from the php tag):

```
<a href="" id="expand_product_images_2978" onclick="expand(<?php echo $id; ?>)">Test</a>
```

Comment: As I am using jquerymobile, instead of using onclick=, can it align the jquerymobile format which uses id="expand_product_image_xxxx"?